# java: Selenium Webdriver: how to get text from element which has style 'display: none'

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, hiddenfield

I have a webelement which on mouse hover displays some text (it is not Tool Tip)
the html code is

```
<div class="total-discout-outer" style="display: block;">
   <div class="total-discout-show">
     <div class="discount-arrow-top"></div>
     <div style="line-height:12px;font-size:13px;"> Promo Applied: (-) Rs 2</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

now as soon as the mouse moves a little bit here or there the text disappears
the html for it is

```
<div class="total-discout-outer" style="display: none;">
   <div class="total-discout-show">
     <div class="discount-arrow-top"></div>
     <div style="line-height:12px;font-size:13px;"> Promo Applied: (-) Rs 2</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

i tried to generate xpath for it and checked it with XPathChecker it worked fine but with selenium its giving NoSuchElement exception

the xpath i used is

```
 //div[contains(@style,'display: none')]//div[contains(text(),'Promo')]
```

i also tried

```
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='discounted-price']"))).build().perform();
    System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.className("total-discount-show")).getText());
```

"discounted price" is the webelement which on hover shows the promo text
but the above is also giving NoSuchElementException.
now how do i get text from this .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but with `.getAttribute("style")` on that div you will get the value as String!

Answer (score 0):

In my case Js code is working please have a look

```
public static string GetValueFromele(IWebElement element, IWebDriver Driver)
    {
        IJavaScriptExecutor javaScriptExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Driver;
        string value = javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML", element) as string;

        return value;
    }
```