# Angular Protractor retrieve text from div element returns null

Tags: javascript, angular, selenium-webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

I have the following structure I want to query for some e2e angular test with protractor:

```
<div id='parentId'>
   <div>First</div>
   <div>Second</div>
   <div>Third</div>
   <div>Four</div>
</div>
```

Currently I want to retrieve a list of the texts of the child div elements :

```
['First','Second', 'Third', 'Fourth']
```

I remember being able to do so with *protractor* in Angular some time ago but I can't get it to work now.

Current code I have is:

*mytest.e2e-spec.ts*:

```
import { browser, element, ElementArrayFinder, WebElement } from 'protractor';

describe('A test here ', () => { 
    it('should find the texts in all four divs', async () => {
          const elements: WebElement[] = await element.all(by.css('#parentId > div')).getWebElements();
          let array = await Promise.all(mocks.map(async (item)=>{
             let text = await item.getText();
             // let text = await item.getAttribute('innerText'); = null
             // let text = await item.getAttribute('innerHTML'); = null
             // let text = await item.getAttribute('value'); = null
             // let text = await item.getAttribute('textContent'); = null
            return text;
          }));
          console.log(array);
     
     }

});
```

The above code returns ['null', 'null', 'null', 'null']

I can get the tagName and length of the `WebElement` returned array from the query properly. However, so far the text query keeps returning 'null'.

I have tried without even looping and:

```
await elements[0].getText();
```

will also produce null.

Also tried following queries instead:

```
const elms0: WebElement[] = await (await browser.driver.findElement(by.id('parentId'))).findElements(by.tagName('div'));


const elms: WebElement[] = await browser.driver.findElements(by.css('#parentId > div'));
```

they both return the length of the elements correctly, however the text returns always null or empty. I suspect this has to do with my async operation somehow racing, but I have tried all remedies out there, nothing seems to work so far. :/

Currently using protractor 7.0.0 , although the same version has been working before. Already went through related questions, I don't think there is anything I haven't tried yet.

Using chrome driver on a MacOS.

**EDIT:**  The parent div had **display:none** as its styling which made it impossible to fetch the text.

Comment: getText sounds like it is currently broken with Chrome 91. I would check the Chrome + ChromeDriver version.

Comment: Similar problems are noted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67813538/element-getattributevalue-returns-null-in-protractor

Possible fix is to get off of 91 or wait till Chrome / ChromeDriver fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If this won't work

```
describe('A test here ', () => { 
    it('should find the texts in all four divs', async () => {
          const elements = element.all(by.css('#parentId > div'));
          let array = await elements.getText();
          console.log(array);
     })
});
```

then you likely to have either issue:

- elements are not visible. But in this case `.getText()` would returns `''` unless a recent update changed it
- this is chrome version specific problem that has been reported [element.getAttribute('value') returns null in Protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67813538/element-getattributevalue-returns-null-in-protractor)

PS. I used javascript syntax

Answer (score 0):

As @Sergey assumed, it was indeed another issue on my side.

the `parentDiv` had `display:none` as its style. Selenium WebDriver was somehow detecting the whole DOM structure but not the texts. Further posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60220995/how-can-i-get-text-from-display-none-element-using-java-selenium), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20012442/using-selenium-can-i-get-the-text-of-an-invisible-element/24336401) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906393/java-selenium-webdriver-how-to-get-text-from-element-which-has-style-display) led to more and more confusion. It seems it is not possible to get text of `div`
element if it is hidden.